# Limit of a certain sequence of R.V's

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $\zeta_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d N(0,1) r.v's in the same space.
Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in (0,1)$ to be constants. Define $x_0 = x$ and
$$
  x_n = a x_{n-1} + \zeta_n.
$$

The first part of the exercise is to calculate the limit of $x_n$ and say in which sense we have this limit.

One can show that $x_n = a^n x + \sum_{k=1}^n a^{n-k}\zeta_k$. So it is easy to show a convergence in distribution just by calculating the mean and variance of $x_n$ and showing that this converges. I am just curious if there is any stronger convergence, I tried in $L^2$ and with a tedious calculation one can show that $x_n$ is not Cauchy. I suspect it also doesn't converge in $L^1$. The almost surely convergence seems a bit hopeless to me because the sequence $\{\zeta_k(\omega)\}_k$ is almost surely unbounded. I 
But I did not manage to study this limit in probability thought.

Is my intuition wrong, could this thing converge in $L^1$, a.s or in probability?

Comment: Are the $\zeta_n$ iid?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I will add that.

Comment: Are you sure that convergence of mean and variance is enough to show convergence in distributions?

Comment: In the case of the normals, yeah, I think so. Because the characteristic functions will converge pointwise to the desired characteristic function and then you use Lévy continuity theorem.

Comment: Convergence in probability plus Boundedness in $L^p$ implies convergence in $L^q$ for $q < p.$ So if you showed that there is no convergence in $L^2$ you should already have proven that convergence in probability is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show $X_n$ converges in none of the other senses, it suffices to show it does not converge in probability. Consider, for $m<n$, 
$$
X_n-X_m = (a^n-a^m)x + \sum_{k=1}^m (a^{n-k}-a^{m-k})\xi_k+\sum_{k=m+1}^n a^{n-k}\xi _k
$$
This is a normal variable with mean $(a^n-a^m)x$ and variance greater than $1$. This means $P(|X_n-X_m|>1)>0.32$, and in particular, $P(|X_n-X_m|>1)\not\to0$ as $m,n\to\infty$. This shows $X_n$ is not Cauchy in probability, so does not converge in probability.

---

As a side note, once you've shown that $x_n$ is not Cauchy, you've proven it doesn't converge almost surely.